# Machine learning approach to a selection problem

Tags: machine-learning

I'm thinking how to tackle such a problem.

Let's say we have a set of products, each have some numeric characteristics `(x1, x2, x3)`. A customer is given a choice of `n` such products and buys one. Only a few of products are shown and the choice is made only between them based solely on the characteristics. The number of products for selection varies. Now assuming that I have a good amount of data describing the sets given for choice and the choice made, how do I build a model to predict the outcome of similar experiment in the future? That is, we give `n` products and want to find which will be the choice based on their characteristics.

My first thought was neural network, but that would work only if I have a constant set of inputs and here it varies. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have you consider this is a discrete choice problem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more of a [ranking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank) problem, since you need to pick one item out of a set. There's a number of algorithms available, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also take a look at P. Diaconis papers on "Random Walk with Reinforcement" and "Reinforcement Learning" approaches

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [collaborative filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering) for this! It's used all the time for similar problems.

Comment: As I mentioned, the subject of research is not preference of users but 'goodness' of products. This method is more about recognizing preferences of specific users...

Answer (score 0):

I think that is is similar to so called [conjoint analysis.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjoint_analysis_%28marketing%29)
Statistical technique used in marketing.
It especially determines how people value different features.

Comment: Yes, but that's not an approach to the problem, just one of the ways of classifying it...